# How can I make threads that do 1/4 of a function?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having an application that calculates the prime numbers of the user input. so if the user puts 10 in the console. Then it will show every prime number from 0 to 10. Now If I do something like 10000000 it will take a long time before it shows every prime number so I want to divide it by 4 threads, so that each thread can do 1/4 of the total number. So the first thread does from 0 till 250000, the second thread does the calculations from 250000 till 500000, etc. this is my code so far, what I'm doing with this code now is that I have 1 thread that calculates the prime of the number that the user puts in and in the end I'm making a sum of the values in the array.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace WeekOpdr__5
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static int[] deel1 = new int[10000];

        static int n;
        static int startNumber;
        static int secondNumber;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("type a number in: ");
                n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int start1 = 2;
                int threadCount = 4;
                var threads = new Thread[threadCount];
                sw.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
                {

                    int range = n / threadCount * 2;

                    Console.WriteLine(range);
                    secondNumber = n / 2;
                    int start2 = start1;
                    threads[i] = new Thread(() => PrimeNumbers(startNumber, range ));
                    //threads[i] = new Thread(() => PrimeNumbers(secondNumber, n));
                    threads[i].Start();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
                {
                    threads[i].Join();
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"The Prime Numbers between 0 and {n} are : ");
                sw.Restart();
                ReturnN();
                SumN();
                long timeElapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"\nthe total time is {timeElapsed} ms");
            }
            
            

            static void PrimeNumbers(int startNumber, int n)
            {

                int position = 0;
                for (int i = startNumber; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    bool primeDetected = true;

                    for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
                    {
                        if (i % j == 0)
                        {
                            primeDetected = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (primeDetected && i != 1)
                    {
                        deel1[position++] = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            static void ReturnN()
            {
                foreach (int i in deel1)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{i} ");
                }

            }

            static void SumN()
            {
                int sum = deel1.Sum();
                Console.WriteLine($"\nDe som van de priemgetallen tussen 2 en {n}: {sum}");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing the multithreading and every thread makes a new array so the numbers between 0 and 25% makes array1, between 25% and 50% makes array2 etc. and in the end merging all of thes arrays in to 1 big array so I can make a sum of it

Comment: Not quite what your question is, but why do you test for divisors like `for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)`?    Why not go up to Math.sqrt(i)?  You could also test 2 and then test odd numbers.

Comment: So multithreading correctly is extremely hard if you don’t know all pitfalls. As well as unnecessarily low-level. In general use Tasks for asynchronous code or Parallel.For/ForEach for parallel processing. The latter can be configured to use 4 threads and will distribute the work automatically and evenly.